# Coordinate system - ArcMap and Mapinfo

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, mapinfo

I am not sure if someone already asked this question, but I am having trouble to understanding MapInfo and I only recently started working with ArcMap.

I have done a map (different shp files) in a coordinate system MGI Balkan 6 (the coordinate system I need), but when the client opens this map (shp.files) in MAPInfo the coordinate system they see is not in the "fitting" coordinate system.

How can I solve this problem in ArcMap so when I send it to them they could see it appropriately?

Comment: I'm not sure I undertand what you mean by "fitting". Do the shapefiles not align with each other? Do they not display in MGI Balkan 6?

Comment: They align with each other in ArcMap, but when she opens it in MapInfo she said that the projected coordinate system is displayed completely in a different zone. 
Her image does not match my image. When I open basemap and compare it it fits the borders. But when she opens it via MapInfo she sees the shp files in South Africa for example...And I do not know how to fix this situation.

Answer (score 3):

When you add data to an ArcMap project the data are contained within a data frame.  This data frame can have a defined coordinate reference system (CRS) - in your case you either set it to MGI Balkan 6 or the first shapefile you added was referencing was using MGI Balkan 6 and ArcMap defined the CRS for the data frame for you.  Any shapefile can have its own CRS but ArcMap will do 'projection on the fly' for you so even if different shapefiles reference different CRSs ArcMap will sort out the issues and display them in the same place for you.
I have not used MapInfo but I am guessing that either MapInfo is not doing 'projection on the fly' or there is a setting that is not set to do projection on the fly.  MapInfo is making some assumption about the CRS and displaying the data where it thinks it should go - in this case Africa.  The solution would be to reproject all of your data to MGI Balkan 6 before sharing.  Tell the MapInfo user to ensure her MapInfo project is referencing MGI Balkan 6 and everything should line up for her as well.